# Few issues after installing Visual Studio 2015 Community edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community edition to checkout the different feature. Before that I was using VS 2013 for development. Few issues that I am facing after installing VS 2015 are

1) Package manager is not able to download few of the assemblies like Microsoft.Data.OData,Microsoft.Data.Edm

2) Solution which was building successfully in VS 2013 now gives a alert saying symbol not loaded for a particular project. No such alerts in VS2015.

I am not 100% sure these are related to VS 2015 but there are no other changes done which explains these issues.

Let me know if anyone else is also facing these issues or knows solution.

Comment: "is not able to download" - what's exact error message? Have you customized `Nuget.targets` someway?

Comment: "Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more information.  Packages affected: EntityFramework, Microsoft.Net.Http"

Comment: FYI one of my colleague facing the same issues. So definitely it is something to do with VS 2015.

Comment: Error message tells, that you've changed target framework for some projects(s). And yes, in this case you need to reinstall packages. There's no deal with VS here - e.g., using VS 2013 and changing target framework from 4.0 to 4.5.1 requires reinstall of EF too.

Comment: @Dennis There is no change in the target framework/project file and it is working fine for other guys who havent installed VS2015. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the answer, so posting because this question shows in search results; comment from prashant is correct (in my case)

In my situation, we use a Git repo, all working fine on one laptop. I cloned to another laptop and I was getting this error on build, same version of VS 2015.

Reinstalling the nuget packages from the Package Manager Console worked

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

As detailed here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

edit: incidentally the issue seems to have arisen from someone changing the target framework for the projects, but not checking in the changes to the nuget packages/configs which were still targeting 4.5.2